# How to query mongoose through nested id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a "Follow" schema like this:

```
var Follow = mongoose.model('Follow', new mongoose.Schema({
personWhoFollow_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
},
personWhoIsFollowed_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
}}));
```

And the query I made when user request with params id is like:

```
Follow.findOne({personWhoFollow_id: req.params.id}, function(err, follow){});
```

It doesn't work! I tried to console.log(follow) and I get this error:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "favicon.ico" at path "personWhoFollow_id" for model "Follow"', and some long objects

Comment: Define "doesn't work". It could mean _anything_.

Comment: thanks for reminding me this. Updated!

Comment: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "favicon.ico" - this suggests misconfigured routing. Request from browser for favicon somehow is translated into that query. Obviously, `"favicon.ico"` does not look _anything_ like object id.

Comment: in express id you define a route such as `follow/:id` and another route `follow/favicon.ico` you have to define `follow/favicon.ico` first orelse it will take `favicon.ico` as an id param.

I would guess you have something like this going on.
Either that or you are just sending `favicon.ico` as an id for some other reason by mistake